# Make audio play on click in iOS 5.1.1+

Tags: ios, html, mobile, mobile-safari, html5-audio

I've been surfing around for a simple example of how to achieve audio playback onclick in iOS but I can't seem to find one. I understand that Apple has disabled autoplay due to data usage considerations - but what I'm trying to do is have audio play when a user clicks on an image - I'm by no means a master at javascript and I can't find a simple example to apply to my code so I'm hoping someone could demonstrate how you'd do this.

I entered a simplified version of my code below. I'm already using a javascript function to determine whether or not I need serve up an ogg file or mp3 file when the image is clicked. I am also using a JQuery plugin that zooms in on the image when clicked, another that controls some of the font sizes of a couple headlines on the page and a third for chromeframe. I have two separate script tags in the head because I couldn't figure out how to get them all to work in one tag. I know this is sloppy and I'm planning to clean it up, but before I do I'd like to figure out the audio issue.

Anyway, I thought because I already had the audio set up to play on the click of the image it would work in iOS but it's not and I'm not sure how I should adjust the code. If someone has the time to provide a simple example as a starting point as to how to do this I'd really appreciate it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.zoomooz.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.fittext.js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1/CFInstall.min.js"></script>
<script>

// Mouseover/ Click sound effect- by JavaScript Kit (www.javascriptkit.com)
// Visit JavaScript Kit at http://www.javascriptkit.com/ for full source code

//** Usage: Instantiate script by calling: var uniquevar=createsoundbite("soundfile1",       "fallbackfile2", "fallebacksound3", etc)
//** Call: uniquevar.playclip() to play sound

var html5_audiotypes={ //define list of audio file extensions and their associated audio    types. Add to it if your specified audio file isn't on this list:
"mp3": "audio/mpeg",
"mp4": "audio/mp4",
"ogg": "audio/ogg",
"wav": "audio/wav"
 }

 function createsoundbite(sound){
var html5audio=document.createElement('audio')
if (html5audio.canPlayType){ //check support for HTML5 audio
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
        var sourceel=document.createElement('source')
        sourceel.setAttribute('src', arguments[i])
        if (arguments[i].match(/\.(\w+)$/i))
            sourceel.setAttribute('type', html5_audiotypes[RegExp.$1])
        html5audio.appendChild(sourceel)
    }
    html5audio.load()
    html5audio.playclip=function(){
        html5audio.pause()
        html5audio.currentTime=0
        html5audio.play()
    }
    return html5audio
}
else{
    return {playclip:function(){throw new Error("Unfortunately your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio")}}
}
 }

 //Initialize two sound clips with 1 fallback file each:

 var mouseoversound=createsoundbite("example1.ogg", "example1.mp3")
 var clicksound=createsoundbite("example2.ogg", "example2.mp3")
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){
            if($(window).width()>0){
                $("li.fittext").fitText(1.68);
                $("#footerwrap p").fitText(5);
            };
        });
        $(".zoomTarget").click(function(evt) {
                evt.stopPropagation();
                evt.preventDefault();
                $(this).zoomTo({debug:true});
                $(this).zoomTo({easing:'ease-in'});
            });

            $(window).click(function(evt) {
                evt.stopPropagation();
                $("body").zoomTo({targetsize:1.0});
            });

            // for iPhone
            $("#container").click(function(evt) {
                evt.stopPropagation();
                $("body").zoomTo({targetsize:1.0});
            });

            $("body").zoomTo({targetsize:1.0});


        $(window).load(function() {
            CFInstall.check({
             mode: "overlay",
             destination: "http://www.waikiki.com"
           });
           });



</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<img onclick="clicksound.playclip()" class="zoomTarget" data-targetsize="1.0" data-duration="10000" easing="linear" src="images/image.jpg"/>
</div><!--wrapper--> 

</body>
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Please share solution if you have found one.